# Pandas, dataframe value "#-##" exporting as date in csv

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe values in a column that should be outputted as ie `3-12` , however in excel it is outputted into data format as `2020-03-12`. Is there a way I can keep format as is?

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by keep the format as is , in excel or pandas ?

Comment: keep it as `3-12` , I guess in pandas it remains the same, but upon exporting to excel it changes.

Comment: Then it is excel question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of the EXCEL column. It worked for me. :)